# How to override default spring integration configuration

Tags: spring-integration

For example:
xmlns:int-jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jdbc"

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter.......
```

I want this to use my custom implementation, so i need to know 
1) What class it uses (so i can extend it and override whatever)
2) than how do i tell it to use my new class rather than the default one.

is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to inject your own implementation using the XML namespace, but you can simply wire up `<bean/>` definitions. After all, that's all that the namespace parser does.

In this case, you need a bean of class `SourcePollingChannelAdapterFactoryBean` which needs `PollerMetadata` and a `source` (and creates a `SourcePollingChannelAdapter`), with the `source` being a bean of class `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` (which is a `MessageSource`).

So you would subclass the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`.

If you think your implementation will have wide appeal, please open a JIRA issue and consider contributing it.

Comment: Thanks Gary, is there a easy way to know what </bean> definitions are produced by a schema based configuration.

Comment: Not currently; you have to dig in to the namespace parsers, such as the [JDBC adapter parser](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/jdbc/config/JdbcPollingChannelAdapterParser.java) and its superclass. Another alternative (with Spring Integration 4.0) is to use java `@Configuration` and the `@InboundChannelAdapter` annotation on a `@Bean` of type `MessageSource`.